# How to get current (aka displaying) page id in Confluence programmatically, e.g. REST API?

Tags: confluence, jira-rest-java-api, confluence-rest-api

How to get current (aka displaying) page id in Confluence programmatically, e.g. REST API?

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way is to get it from `AJS` like this:

```
var   pageId = AJS.params.pageId;
```

Another method is to get it from `<meta>` elements of the current page:

```
var   pageId = undefined;
var   metas = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
for (i = 0; i < metas.length; ++i)
{
    if (metas[i].name == "ajs-page-id")
    {
        pageId = metas[i].content;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the API Documentation, you can use following REST Call to Find a Page by Title and Space Key:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X GET "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content?title=myPage%20Title
&spaceKey=TST&expand=history" | python -mjson.tool
```

Above call will gives you the ID as well. Please check the API [Documentations](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples) for further details.